# Change text and color ionic button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have ionic button

```
  <ion-button expand="block" share="round" (click)="connectOrdisconnect()" [disabled]="(loading$ | async)"> 
    <ion-label > <ion-spinner *ngIf="loading$ | async"></ion-spinner> connectOrdisconnect</ion-label>
  </ion-button>


  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading$=this.printService.printerConnecting;  
    this.loading$.subscribe(es => {
       
      //how to change the color and text of ion-button 

      // setTimeout need to run without troubles with ng changes detector
      setTimeout(_=>{this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()},0);    
    });
  }
```

am using ionic 5 form ..i need to change the text and color (blue/red) based on loading$ observable value chages..Please let me knw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add your custome color like I added gold color in my code sample similarly you can add your own color in your project and use it

**variable.scss**

```
--ion-color-gold: #ffd700;
--ion-color-gold-rgb: 255, 215, 0;
--ion-color-gold-contrast: #000000;
--ion-color-gold-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
--ion-color-gold-shade: #e0bd00;
--ion-color-gold-tint: #ffdb1a;
```

**global.scss**

```
.ion-color-gold {
    --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-gold) !important;
    --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-gold-rgb) !important;
    --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-gold-contrast) !important;
    --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-gold-contrast-rgb) !important;
    --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-gold-shade) !important;
    --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-gold-tint) !important;
}
```

**In your ts file Define a variable like below**

```
public buttonCustomColor : string = 'primary';
public buttonCustomText : string = 'Connect';

constructor() { 
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.buttonCustomColor  = 'gold';
      this.buttonCustomText = 'Disconnect';
    },5000)
}
```

**Use this buttonCustomColor variable in your html like mentioned below**

```
<ion-button [color]="buttonCustomColor" expand="block" share="round" (click)="connectOrdisconnect()" [disabled]="(loading$ | async)"> 
    <ion-label > <ion-spinner *ngIf="loading$ | async"></ion-spinner> {{buttonCustomText}}</ion-label>
</ion-button>
```